# Error while installing QGIS on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to install QGIS for ubuntu 20.04 with this guide https://freegistutorial.com/install-qgis-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/

I managed step one and successfully installed and upgraded`gnupg software-properties-common`, but when trying out step 2 i get the following message:

```
gpg: key 46B5721DBBD2996A: public key "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2021) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
```

While it says that the key's been processed and imported, when I try to confirm it with `gpg --fingerprint (public key)`, i get:

```
gpg: error reading key: No public key
```

I went on https://debian.qgis.org/debian/ to confirm I'm getting the `qgis.gpg.key` file and replaced the 2020 from the tutorial with 2021 that is visible in the directory, but that didn't help either, I'm still getting the same error and I don't understand why

Any information will be wildly helpful

EDIT: I downloaded my QGIS installer from https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html, i got the "Long Term Release" and the file is named `QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.28.4-3.msi`

SOLVED (i think): I found a different tutorial (https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_ubuntu.html) and installed `QGIS` with `sudo-apt-get`. Now when i type `qgis` in my terminal, the program starts although it's probably going to come back to bite me later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than picking random tutorials you should use the [actual QGis instructions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu),

```
sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common
sudo mkdir -m755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings 
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

then add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: your-distributions-codename
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gpg --edit-key 46B5721DBBD2996A
```

This will open the GPG interactive shell for the specified key. Inside the shell, you can use the trust command to set the level of trust. For ultimate trust, type:

```
trust
```